# How to control collapse function on specific screen sizes

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I am currently building a responsive website where i am using collapsable panels for the content. I am only looking to use the collapsable function for smartphones due to the massive amount of content.

So i have two scenarios:

1. Tablets and smartphones with minimal screen space
2. Desktop screens with enough screen space

Basically i want the collapse function to work only on `scenario 1`, where all panels are uncollapsed as default. In `scenario 2` all panels should just be open and the collapse function should be disabled.

Since i am using Bootstrap `collapse.js`, is there a good way to handle this task?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A media query can be used to prevent your panels from collapsing on larger viewports.

**CSS:**

```
@media (min-width: 992px) { /*or 1200px if you just want it to affect the lg devices*/
  .collapsing {
    height: auto !important;
  }
  .collapse {
    height: auto !important;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

As described in the doc here: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#collapse, the collapse plugin uses three classes to define the different states of the collapsed element: .collapse (display is set to none), .collapse.in (display is set to block) and .collapsing (when the element is transitioning).  The media query above takes advantage of these and sets the collapse state to display block.  However, you need to also override the inline height styles that are applied when the javascript is run, so using height: auto !important on both the collapse and collapsing state, causes the inline styles to be ignored in favor of the !important rule.

**EDIT**

See the comments below.   If you find that the content doesn't display as expected, try adding  `visibility: visible;` to the `.collapse` rule in the above media query.

Comment: Almost did the job, the content of the text is hidden for some odd reason.

Comment: Can you provide some markup? a fiddle or bin or something?  Seems to be working for me using the panel markup on from the doc under the collapse content I linked to above, and I've used this technique for something similar successfully in the past.  Maybe it's something to do with some other css conflict?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jme11/4ape8r5p/ This seems to work consistently on my end on FF 32, Safari 7.1 and Chrome 38 (MAC OSX).  Of course, it could still possibly result from a specific browser issue.  Which browser are you testing in?

Comment: Its very odd. I made a minimal version which seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/5Lhh0991/

Comment: When i look in the chrome inspector i see `.collapse {display:none;visibility: hidden;}`

Comment: Hmmm, ok, well then, visibility: visible should do it, but I wonder where that's coming from... does it have a line number?

Comment: Seems very strange.. I have commented out all of my styles and even additional JavaScript..

Comment: Can't find that reference anywhere in 3.2.0 or even in 3.1.1 and I did find that on the nonresponsive.css, they basically use the same technique that I recommended for the navbar toggle: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/49519e981614fb8e0c4fabcbb0a632db292c2b3c/docs/examples/non-responsive/non-responsive.css (see line 61 ).  Can you add the visibility: visible to the .collapse media query?  I'd like to know if it does the trick for you so I can update my answer.  Perhaps it will help someone else in the future.  Also, I'd love to know which point release of Bootstrap 3 you are using.

Comment: I have the latest version from git, compiled with LESS files. I added the visibility which solved the problem.

Comment: Strange, visibility doesn't seem to be in any of the stable releases.   I rechecked the latest dist files and the component-animations.less file and don't find any use of the visibility property there.  Either way, I'm glad it ultimately worked for you.

Comment: Took a while, but thanks to the Chrome inspector tool its pretty convenient to look through the masses of style. Thanks for your effort! :)